# ruby access to value in sequel response

Tags: ruby, associations, sequel

I have a problem accessing value from Sequel response. It is only my lack of knowledge, I am new to Sequel.

I am writing website where I ask for articles, then I send query for categories (associated with ID in model), so I have 2 variables to iterate.

I do this

```
    @articles.each_with_index do |article, i|
      article.id
      article.author
      ...
```

And I have also value for categories, when I iterate it with pry, I receive good data

```
@cat.each do |category|
  category.each do |c|
    puts c
  end
end
```

gives me perfect output with name of the col "category_cz" and value.

So I tried to do upper block and fill in the name of the category in my language.

```
@articles.each_with_index do |article, i|
      article.id
      article.author
      @cat[i].???.category_cz
end
```

I don't know how to access values where are ???, I tried combinations based on my associations.

Way I am sending queries.

```
@articles = Article.association_join(:articles_data_cz).select
binding.pry
@cat = Article.association_join(:category).select(:category_cz)
```

And I have associations between table Article and Category models.

in category:

```
one_to_one :articles
```

in article:

```
  many_to_one :articles_data_cz, key: :article_cz
  many_to_one :articles_data_en, key: :article_en
  many_to_one :category, key: :category
```

I know this is my stupidity and lack of knowledge, I tried a lots of combinations and I cannot guess from docs.

Please, any suggestion?

Thanks

M.

Comment: I think you messed up your associations. I can't really understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to put each article into exactly one category? Or do you want to add categories to articles? First we need to know what kind of association you want to have then we can help you setting up those associations and how you get the right responses.

Comment: Ah, yes, I am sorry, I am trying to add name of the category, instead of number, which is stored in article table. I have tables "articles" where are basic article infos with foreign key to articles_data_en and articles_data_cz for language versions, and table categories, where are categories for articles, table articles has 3 foreign keys category(int), article_cz(int) and article_en(int). Every row in category has one_to_one to each language, and every article has one category. I made many_to_one in articles to category and one_to_one in category to articles.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, sequel didn't guess my table name correctly, so I played with associations, now I am accessing all values through the instance of the object of model, and everything works perfectly. For the others, who might be stuck, check the correctness of the association.